# JSONata: words to lowerCamelCase

Tags: camelcasing, jsonata

I have a string consisting of words and punctuation, such as "Accept data protection terms / conditions (German)". I need to normalize that to camelcase, removing punctuation.

My closest attempt so far fails to camelcase the words, I only manage to make them into kebab-case or snake_case:

```
$normalizeId := function($str) <s:s> {
        $str.$lowercase()
            .$replace(/\s+/, '-')
            .$replace(/[^-a-zA-Z0-9]+/, '')
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anindya's answer works for your example input, but if `(German)` was not capitalized, it would result in the incorrect output:

```
"acceptDataProtectionTermsConditionsgerman"
```

[Link to playground](https://www.stedi.com/jsonata/playground?statev2=eJyVkNtqwzAMQH9FmEBtlttuD2u3QR%2F3C4tTMI5XAqltLIeNLvv3KRdYu7GH6kVYOjrIqiqGrg%2FasJSZDx8MYussPdRQDteUJdtqbXyERkUFPrhodCQEogkHhAK0s007VhD4nmrKCslokEsLFEnvvQmwfoK33k6TPFECPufuRKh8H1zvsSrrfMa1QsPFjHxtpF1UnXu%2FRDXhv1VjXnTW0bZdezQvzbkUYxDwiGt8PpNTOU%2BC8Z3ShhdSIs9FkS4%2FFD%2FgGCdgtctUdtxmr2X2UF%2FRwGr1P7xbnNPufy9wsjJPEkENQad2w81wO9yxOmX3rP4Gy0uIng%3D%3D)

---

This version would work and prevent that bug:

```
(
  $normalizeId := function($str) <s:s> {
        $str
            /* normalize everything to lowercase */
            .$lowercase()
            /* replace any "punctuations" with a - */
            .$replace(/[^-a-zA-Z0-9]+/, '-')
            /* Find all letters with a dash in front,
               strip the dash and uppercase the letter */
            .$replace(/-(.)/, function($m) { $m.groups[0].$uppercase() })
            /* Clean up any leftover dashes */
            .$replace("-", '')
  };

  $normalizeId($$)
  /* OUTPUT: "acceptDataProtectionTermsConditionsGerman" */
)
```

[Link to playground](https://www.stedi.com/jsonata/playground?statev2=eJx9Uu1qwjAUfZVLKNi6pnVfP%2BY%2BQAaDvcKaDkJ7tYGahCSdU%2Bu7L22d4hzePyEn95x77iFZRqxqTIEkJvitDVorlPQX3k7aa38yMisK1A5K7jhooxwWzreAQ7O0kEKhZCk6xEK48BiXESOeGDIJEEjlkVps8L2E6TPMG9mzw8A6E8GTndoX2HadQ3Xw8dZVOoaDBuAXmrWrhFyAU1CrFZqCW4RxekpKgsNbGJ3pGdQ1LxC4XAMjurPU8H4DRmAlXAUc6D%2Bae16YZp%2BU082MfkzoQ36VxjCio%2FMxb0KWwOsaanQ%2BLPsrXXJbgZAwN0q6%2BJTmyycgNLgKh0buRRqt94t28CB3yR8Nk8i7Ooa9jGALwTJZGNVom03yJDhohhHszs2%2F1silH9yHVOPcKR997wjthdGMUEZ8HkMcu0cm%2F%2F6CMAj8W%2BQ%2FiGpv2tv2juQxuSf5D3ApvQA%3D)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Nice alternative for try.jsonata! It supports the older v1.7.0, can I make it use v1.8.6?

Comment: @dschulten unfortunately it doesn't have support for v1.8.6 _yet_. We're planning on adding it in the near future, though!

Comment: Hey @dschulten! Just wanted to let you know that https://www.stedi.com/jsonata/playground now supports v1.8.6 :)

Comment: great, will take a look

Answer (score 1):

You should target the letters which has a space in front, and capitalize them by using this regex `/\s(.)/`.

Here is my snippet: (Edited

```
(
    $upper := function($a) {
        $a.groups[0].$uppercase()
    };
    
    $normalizeId := function($str) <s:s> {
        $str.$lowercase()
            .$replace(/[^-a-zA-Z0-9]+/, '-')
            .$replace(/-(.)/, $upper)
            .$replace(/-/, '')
    };

    $normalizeId("Accept data protection terms / conditions (German)");
)

/* OUTPUT: "acceptDataProtectionTermsConditionsGerman" */
```

> Edit: Thanks @vitorbal. The "$lower" function on regex replacement earlier was not necessary, and did not handle the scenario you mentioned. Thanks for pointing that out. I have updated my snippet as well as added a link to the playground below.

[Link to playground](https://www.stedi.com/jsonata/playground?statev2=eJx9kE1LxDAQQP%2FKEAJNsGnr18FdFXoQ8erRtkJIx6XQJiFJUdb4381uFSyicxky8%2BYxk6Yh3sxOIckJvlmH3g9Gp4eMVTxNuSW1UmgD9DJIsM4EVCEhENBNHkpQRvfDoeKB3d89TrXmLUmDrNWQgs7WooPNDbzM%2BjjJqOTwvnSPhCx2zszWN1VXLLiSHhlfkI%2Ftkr902rhJjsMeH%2Fq11AfH4dpv%2FO1KnsoFHc3rWvodBXVoR6mQlc2zkGJfi6dKXHUnZQ6ZyP6mBSt4YpZ1%2F8EOnuzHJb%2BvYJTy1ODpy0w8i%2BfxgnQ5uSTdJ41idPI%3D)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, very helpful!